# Permutations and Combinations - Roads.

Tags: graph-theory

There are ten roads linking all possible pairs of five cities. It is known that there is at least one crossing of two roads, as illustrated in the diagram below on the left. There are nine roads linking each of three cities to each of three towns. It is known that there is also at least one crossing of two roads, as illustrated in the diagram below on the right. Of the fifteen roads linking all possible pairs of six cities, what is the minimum number of crossings of two roads?

[image: Figure for above question]

I tried solving this problem using permutations, as 15P6=3603600, which doesn't seem to be right.   Please advise.

Comment: This is a topological question. It's about how to lay this graph out on the paper, permutations have nothing to do with it. If a graph is not planar (has a genus >0), then you cannot lay it out on paper without self-intersections. You need to characterize your graph topologically, I think computing the genus is the right way forward. Your graph is actually just the complete graph over 6 vertices, so there might be literature on that.

Comment: The search term is "crossing number". I bet if you type "crossing number complete graph" into the internet, you'll get an answer.

Comment: Indeed, go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Complete_graphs_and_graph_coloring and post an answer based on what you find there.

Comment: Place a sixth city/node in the centre of the left hand diagram and connect it to each of the other five cities. Two additional road crossings are required. This shows that the crossing number for $K_6$ is at most 3.

Comment: Thank You @GerryMyerson and gandalf61   :  I used the formula suggested by H. F. JENSEN in his paper "An Upper Bound for the Rectilinear Crossing Number of the Complete Graph" ; with n=6 cities/nodes as : number of crossings <= (7*(6^4)-56(6^3)+128(6^2)+48*6*((6-7)/3)+108)/432   i.e. number of crossings <= 3.69444   i.e.   the crossing number for 6 nodes is at most 3.   Is this correct?   Please advise.

Comment: It's fine, but I think it's overkill for 6 nodes.